# Should i use Linux Pipe/FIFO or a queue,mutex and condition variable for communication between two threads?

Tags: linux, pipe, mutex, condition-variable, locks

What is the efficient way to communicate between two threads in terms of CPU utilization. Should i use Linux Pipe/FIFO which will be lock-less or a message queue, mutex and condition variable for communication between two threads?

Comment: What kind of inter-thread communication? Do you need to exchange data, commands or just synchronize? Also, since memory is shared between threads, there is no need for pipes.

Comment: @LHLaurini Pipes may still be appropriatefor threads. It's true it's not needed for the shared memory part but it is still useful for synchronisation.

Comment: For efficiency - pipes/fifos are not the way to go (they involve to many kernel ctx switches). Use atomics/locks on shared memory. You can even build your own lockfree fifo buffer with that.